# In Caesar cypher file encryption, why does key = 1 not work?

Tags: python, encryption, command-line

I am trying to write a python file to encrypt text files with Caesar cypher.
This is the code I have written so far:

```
import sys
import argparse
import string


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="filein", help="input file")
parser.add_argument("-o", dest="fileout", help="output file")
parser.add_argument("-k", dest="keyin", help="key", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-m", dest="modein", help="mode", type=str) #e or d


# parse our arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
filein = args.filein
fileout = args.fileout
keyin = args.keyin
modein = args.modein



def cipher_cipher_using_lookup(text, key, characters = string.printable, mode = args.modein):
    if key <=0 or key >(len(string.printable)-1):
        print("The key must be between 1 and 99 inclusive")
        return None
        
    n = len(characters)

    if mode == "e" or mode == "E":
        key = key -0

    elif mode == "d" or mode == "D":
        key = n - key

    else:
        print("Invalid mode input. Input either 'e' or 'd'. Case insensitive")
    


    table = str.maketrans(characters, characters[key:]+characters[:key])
    translated_text = text.translate(table)
    return translated_text

def fileCipher(filein, fileout, keyin, modein):
    with open (args.filein, "r") as f_in:
        with open(args.fileout, "w") as f_out:
            for line in f_in:
                lineNew = cipher_cipher_using_lookup(line, key = args.keyin, mode = args.modein) #no characters argument
                
                if args.modein != "e" and args.modein != "E" and args.modein != "d" and args.modein != "D":
                    break
                
                f_out.write(lineNew)
    # print("The file {} has been translated successfully and saved to {}".format(filein, fileout))


fileCipher(filein, fileout, keyin, modein)
```

The issue here is with the `key`. The valid `key` values are from 1 to 99, both numbers inclusive. All keys, except 1, works for encryption and decryption. If I input a text file that has texts and newlines (e.g. after a paragraph, enter, next paragraph) in it, `key` 1 can encrypt it, but when it decrypts, the newlines seem to be omitted. So lines become run-on instead of having proper newlines, unlike the original text. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Read [this article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/) for tips on debugging.

Comment: [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) contains the sequence `0x090a0d0b0c` at the end, i.e. H-Tab, LF, CR, V-Tab and FF. You should remove them (e.g. with `characters = string.printable[:-5]`).

Comment: That's just weird, if I look up "printable" it usually refers to character values 0x20 (space) all the way up to 0x7E. These 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x0b and 0x0c are definitely *control characters*. How the heck is a line feed or carriage return a printable character? Have these people never seen a typewriter?

Comment: I tried Topaco's suggestion and it actually worked, but I'm not too sure why either